# Blog style for custom list in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, blog, view-styles, newsletter

I am trying to display my list in sharepoint as:

**Title 1**
Content content content (Aka field1)

**Title 2**
Content content content (Aka field2)

*(formats applied to title and content)*

**I do not have access to SPD.**

I used to work around by:
- addding custom css through content editor 
- creating custom columns with column value wrapped in HTML 
- setting view style to newsletter

but this no longer works in sp online. I have tried json column formatting, but all view styles seem to render as tables and I can't get the effect of one column on top of another.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try CSR (Client side Rendering), either by creating a [JS Link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) or a [SharePoint Add-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/customize-a-list-view-in-sharepoint-add-ins-using-client-side-rendering).

Answer (score 0):

If this is caused by the switch to the modern ui, then your only option is to build a custom webpart to display the data as desired with SPFx https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview

For modern lists and libraries you will also get the option for Row formatting later this year. However, I don't think it will deliver what you are looking for.